# Creating Windows Phone Picture Gallery

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, gallery, image, media-library

I'm trying to create a Grid Gallery with Pcitures from MediaLibrary, but It results complex in terms of loading heavy pictures.

I tried using a ListBox with WrapPanel and Binding Images in it, works great with light images (less than 100kb) but it's extremely slow and UI stopping with images over 1mb. I was following [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/16/virtualizing-data-in-windows-phone-7-silverlight-applications.aspx) but it's not working properly with heavy images.

I was also using PictureDecoder.decodeStream(stream, 100, 100) to resize the desired pictured but still slow.

Do you have something to suggest? Any Alternative? or any sampleabout grid galleries or grid images(heavy ones) lazyloading? Everything appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434150.aspx
Try to use Picture's GetThumbnail() then put it into PictureDecoder.
The size of thumbnail should be 99 pixels on WP7 and 158 on WP8.
It might be faster.